# Adobe air mp4 encoding for seamless loop

Tags: ios, loops, adobe, mp4

I´m testing an AIR App on iPad 3.
The loop works fine with one mp4, it flickers on restart with another one.
So i think it depends on the encoding.
Any hints how to encode it so that it loops seamless?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you will not be able to get that to work due to the way MP4 playback with hardware is implemented under iOS. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33335884/763355) for an example of a different approach that will work, as long as you are not using full HD 30 FPS video (which the CPU and memory bus cannot handle)